# firebase serve functions not starting

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm posting here first because this seems more likely to be operator error than an actual bug with the firebase CLI itself since I've not been able to find anyone with the same problem I'm experiencing.

I'm running:

- firebase-tools 4.2.1
- node 6.14.4

When I call `firebase serve --only functions` I'm not seeing the same results that I've seen posted across the internet. Rather than:

```
i  functions: {some more info + url here}
+  functions: {url}
```

I'm only seeing:

```
i  functions:
```

When I switch the command to `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` I can see the valid values coming back as I would expect for the hosting details and the index.html page appears to be getting served:

```
i  functions:
i  hosting[{firebase-project-site}]:
+  hosting[{firebase-project-site}]: Local server: http://localhost:5000
```

Edit: Including **index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Am I missing an initialization step here for cloud functions that is preventing them from starting locally? At this point I can't even get a basic hello world to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of your index.js in the `functions` folder that defines your functions.

Comment: index.js file added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I created a new Firebase instance with a different user. The Firebase instance I had created with the previous user was brand new as well, but I did have several other instances of Firebase that I had used with that user previously. I haven't investigated the exact cause, but this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even with `hosting` option no functions are served, as I see in your results, and since there are no errors returned, I would say  that there are no Http functions on your `index.js`.